# how do I attach a description to an imagen in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

first of all I want to thank, because in this community I have found a lot of solutions to my development question. But this time I have a big one. I was looking for an answer to it in google and pdf´s and so on. But it's a complicated question and don't know how exactly ask for it in google. I new in app development. so here I go. I'm trying to do an app that shows the different recipes with photos and description like time that it takes and the difficulty and so.

[explanation of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXqck.jpg)
Apologize because the childish imagen to explain to you but you know (efficiency).

My two questions are:
1) How may I do to attach a description to an image. I mean, I want that the people can add their own recipes and of course I will make a formulary to this, but how may I do to when the people create the recipe that I suppose that it should be an object of a class, the TextView be attached to the bottom of the image automatically. in resume, that the image and the description with their elements be one unique element. I have tried to encapsulate the image and the text view in one layout, but in this case I don't know how to create a new layout once the app is running. ok the user fill the formulary but how to create a new layout on the run. I don't know how to solve this.

2) How may I do to change in the description of the image the quantity of red tomatoes. I mean. if the recipe have 3 in difficulty, 3 of 5, this is settled by the user, but how I do to show 3 red tomatoes of 5 and the other showed in gray?

I know you may say "another Newby" but I have realized that I love programming and in El Salvador (Central America) there´s almost any information about this subject. Again, thanks a lot.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: hi @Christian , if my answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way to achieve that is by using Recycler view. and every time a user adds an item. you can add it to the list and the system will draw a new item for you.

check this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)

let me know if this helps or you need more explanation